# Grails - run check after logging in but before accessing the controller

Tags: grails, spring-security

I want to show a screen the first time a user logs in. Is there a best practice for where to run the check of whether or not the user has logged in before? I'm using the Spring Security Core plugin.

Comment: How is a new user registered?

Comment: A new user is registered with payment. I would prefer to have as little information as possible required for input at that time and to defer some to the first login.

Comment: I have not tested it by myself, but can't you add a field/flag in `User` (Person) to check if the user is a first timer to login and based on that you can redirect user to the desired view?

Comment: I don't see it in the docs: http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/4%20Required%20and%20Optional%20Domain%20Classes.html#4.1%20Person%20Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing built in to Spring Security to do this.  I'm doing something similar, but it is based on whether the user has accepted a license agreement or not.  Here's sample filter code that may do what you want.  It is untested:

```
def filters = {

    neverLoggedIn(controller: "login", invert: true) {
      before = {
        if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
          def authenticatedUser = getLoggedInUserCode()
          if (!authenticatedUser.hasLoggedInBefore) {
            redirect controller: "someFirstLoginController", action: "index"
            return false
          }
        }
      }
      after = { Map model -> }
      afterView = { Exception e -> }
    }
}
```